# Is it possible to work with Quarkus and Authentication Provider?

Tags: spring-security, quarkus

In my system, a microservice is responsible to return user's roles for all other microservices.In the other projects I'm using spring, so I can use [Authentication Provider](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider) to get user's roles. Now I would like to create a project using QUARKUS, but I'm not finding how to get user's roles from my microservice, because in Quarkus' documentation there are only examples showing getting roles from database, JWT and etc..

So,  I would like to know if is it possible to work with Quarkus and something like [Authentication Provider](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider) from Spring. If yes, I would like to see one example.

Quarkus seems so nice, but if it is impossible, I won't be able to use it.

Comment: Spring Security is a lot more mature than Quarkus, so perhaps this is just something that Quarkus hasn't built in yet. I wonder if they'd accept a contribution from you.

Comment: Ow, good idea! I would like to help them.